# How to run script against windows servers WinRM

Tags: powershell, remote-server, winrm

I am trying to run a script that searches/downloads/installs windows updates on remote computers using WinRM. I am running this script as a domain user with Admin access. However, I get an ACCESS Denied error.

Now, I have the script copied over to the remote servers but I am unable to view output to see whether the script is running or not.

OUTPUT I want to see: [image]

```
# Continue running on other servers on error
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

# Server list
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\vm-nonprod.txt"

# Logs
$log = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\log-nonprod.txt"

# Path to script on server list
$scriptpath = "C:\Patch.ps1"

$results = @()

foreach ($server in $servers) {

    try {

        $Credential = Import-CliXml -Path "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\admin.Cred"

        #New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {$scriptpath} -ArgumentList "Y" | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WinPatch.txt
        #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential hhq\admin -FilePath "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Patch.ps1"
        #Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\admin\Documents\Patch.ps1 -Destination 'C:\' -ToSession (New-PSSession –ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output ("Error running script on remote host: " + $server)
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $log
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: @gms0ulman no error. I just can't see if its actually running. I want to see output like (see original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here.

1. Does the script exist on the server?
   Sounds like yes, you have `Patch.ps1` in `C:\` on each `$server`
2. The scriptblock does not run the script - just prints the variable.
   To run it, change `{$scriptpath}` to `{. $scriptpath}` or `{& $scriptpath}`
3. The variable `$scriptpath` is not in the scriptblock scope - you will have to pass it in the `-ArgumentList`

   Change: `{$scriptpath} -ArgumentList "Y"`
   ____To: `{param($p); . $p} -ArgumentList $scriptpath`
4. The argument "Y" is being passed to the scriptbock, not the script. The scriptblock is not looking for it, so this value is being lost.
   Assume you want it to be passed to the script - this needs to be done in the scriptblock:
   `{$scriptpath "Y"}`
5. I would recommend getting rid of `Out-File` until you are happy with the output in the console.

---

Putting it all together:

```
-ScriptBlock {$scriptpath} -ArgumentList "Y" | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WinPatch.txt

-ScriptBlock {param($p); . $p "Y"} -ArgumentList $scriptpath
```

Comment: This is very helpful, It resolved the issue I was having. I now have a new issue where. When I run the script against the remote machine, I get an access denied. NOTE that, I am using a user that has admin access. Maybe I need to run powershell as elevated user on the remote host ?

Comment: @bonafideaf What happens when you RDP to the server, and run the script locally using the same user? (in a non-elevated shell)

Comment: I ended up using PsExec to run the script on my remote servers. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong Invoke-Command commented out. The one that is running only has the user name hhq\admin in the credential parameter. It might be failing due to that because it would be prompting for the password during run-time.

Comment: Apologies, I have fixed the comment. I am running it exactly using `        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {$scriptpath} -ArgumentList "Y" | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WinPatch.txt`. however, I cant see any output that its actually running

Comment: You should try to put a -Verbose to see if there is any output there.